# Is there a python factorial function, that can handle array inputs?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, factorial

I want to calculate the values of a function of 2 variables, where one of the variables is used as the argument of a factorial.

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[1,2,3]]).T
b = np.array([[4,5,6]])

def f1(a,b):
    return a*b

def f2(a,b):
    return a*b / fact(b)
```

where fact(b) is a factorial function, that is to be defined.

Executing f1 yields:

```
f1(a,b)
Out[112]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [12, 15, 18]])
```

This is perfectly the shape of result, that I want.

If I extend the function with a factorial such as f2, this yields an error, no matter what factorial function I used.

I tried an iterative way:

```
def fact(n):
fac = n
for i in range(1, n):
    fac *= i
return fac

a*b / fact(b)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

a recursive way:

```
fact = lambda x: x * fact(x-1) if x > 1 else 1
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

or the numpy way:

```
a*b / np.math.factorial(b)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

None of the approaches is able to interpret the array inputs in the way, the simpler function f1 is calculated, i.e. every element of the result array is calculated using one element of the input arrays (just in a way, that 2 nested loops would do, which I want to avoid).

Is there any factorial function, that can handle an array as input ?

Thank you,
lepakk

Comment: do you want the factorial to be applied on each term?

Comment: `numpy.math` is just the regular `math` module. `numpy` has a lot of stuff lying around in its namespace that's just stuff it imported, or only there for backward compatibility. Generally, if it's not in the numpy docs, you shouldn't assume it's actually a numpy thing.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html)

Comment: Thank you, the scipy.special.factorial is doing exactly what I was looking for. Thumbs up!

Comment: Your first error was produced by trying to give `range` an array argument: `range(1, np.array([1,2]))`.  `math` functions only take numbers or scalars, not multielement arrays. `x > 1` on an array produces a boolean array of the same size; that can't be used in an `if` expression.